# Recyclerview with multiple viewtypes communicating with each other?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible for a RecyclerView with multiple view types to pass data/communicate/listen to each other?

I have a RecyclerView with 3 view-types (Named Top, Middle, Bottom Respectively). I have 2 edittexts located in the 2nd view-type named weight and quantity. And 1 textview in the 3rd view-type that calculates and displays the volume of the weight and quantity entered. I would like the 3rd view-type which contains the total volume to change dynamically on the fly when either the weight or quantity fields are being entered.

[image]

```
class Animal_Volume_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AnimalsArray> mList;
    private double volume = 0;

    Main_Program_Adapter(ArrayList<AnimalsArray> list) {
        this.mList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case AnimalsArray.TOP:
                View top = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.animal_top_layout, parent, false);
                return new Top(top);
            case AnimalsArray.MIDDLE:
                View data = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.animal_middle_layout, parent, false);
                return new Middle(data);
            case AnimalsArray.BOTTOM:
                View footer = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.animal_bottom_layout, parent, false);
                return new Bottom(footer);

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final AnimalsArray object = mList.get(position);

        if (object != null) {
            switch (object.getCategory()) {

                case AnimalsArray.TOP:
                    break;


                case AnimalsArray.MIDDLE:

                    ((Middle) holder).weight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                                      int arg3) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                            //While this edittext is being changed, I would like the 3rd viewtype which contains the volume to be calculated on the fly as the user enters numbers in this field.

                            if (arg0.toString().isEmpty() || arg0.toString().length() <= 0 || arg0.toString().equals("") || arg0.toString() == null || arg0.toString().equals("0") || arg0.toString().startsWith(".")) {
                                ((Middle) holder).weight.setText("0");
                            } else {
                                volume = calculateWarmUpVolume(context, arg0.toString(), ((Middle) holder).quantity.getText().toString());

                            }
                        }
                    });


                    ((Middle) holder).quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                                      int arg3) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                            //While this edittext is being changed, I would like the 3rd viewtype which contains the volume to be calculated on the fly as the user enters numbers in this field.

                            if (arg0.toString().isEmpty() || arg0.toString().length() <= 0 || arg0.toString().equals("") || arg0.toString() == null || arg0.toString().equals("0") || arg0.toString().startsWith(".")) {
                                ((Middle) holder).quantity.setText("0");
                            } else {
                                volume = calculateWarmUpVolume(context, ((Middle) holder).weight.getText().toString(), arg0.toString());

                            }
                        }
                    });

                    break;


                case AnimalsArray.BOTTOM:

                    //Check if double is a whole number. If it is, remove decimal by converting to integer
                    String volumedWeight;
                    if ((volume % 1) == 0) {
                        int roundedVolume = (int) volume;
                        volumedWeight = Integer.toString(roundedVolume);
                    } else {
                        volumedWeight = Double.toString(volume);
                    }

                    ((Bottom) holder).volumeWeight.setText(String.valueOf(volumedWeight));

                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}

    private double calculateWarmUpVolume(Context context, String weight, String quantity) {
        edtedWeight = true;
        if (weight.isEmpty() || weight.length() <= 0 || weight.equals("") || weight == null || quantity.isEmpty() || quantity.length() <= 0 || quantity.equals("") || quantity == null) {

            return 0;
        } else {
            try {
                double volumeWeight = Double.parseDouble(weight) * Double.parseDouble(quantity);
                volume += volumeWeight;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {

            }
        }
        return volume;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        final AnimalsArray object = mList.get(position);

        for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); position++) {
            if (object.getId() == position) {
                return position;
            }
        }
        return object.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mList == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mList != null) {
            AnimalsArray object = mList.get(position);
            if (object != null) {
                return object.getCategory();
            }
        }
        return position;
    }



static class Top extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Context context;
    LinearLayout header;

    Top(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        header = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.header);
    }
}

static class Middle extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Context context;
    EditText weight;
    EditText quantity;

    Middle(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        weight = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        quantity= (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    }
}

static class Bottom extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView volume;

    Bottom(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        volume = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.volumeText);
    }
}
```

```
class AnimalsArray {
    static final int TOP = 0;
    static final int MIDDLE = 1;
    static final int BOTTOM = 2;

    private int category;
    private String animalName;
    private String weight;
    private String quantity;

    AnimalsArray(int mCategory, String mAnimalName, String mWeight, String mQuantity) {

        this.category = mCategory;
        this.animalName = mAnimalName;
        this.weight = mWeight;
        this.quantity = mQuantity;
    }


    public int getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public String getAnimalName() {
        return animalName;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) from Google's Android Architecture together with some interfaces to achieve what you want. Click on the link to read more about `LiveData`

-> Declare `Interfaces` with methods you need your various `ViewHolders` to call to achieve the logic you want

```
interface AnimalVolumeChangeListener{

    public void onAnimalVolumeChanged(int groupId, double previousVolume, double currentVolume);

}

interface TotalVolumeInterface{

    public Pair<LifecycleOwner,LiveData<Double>> getTotalVolume(int groupId);

    public void removeObservers(int groupId);

}
```

-> Pass these interfaces as objects in your Recycler Adapter's constructor.

```
class Animal_Volume_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AnimalsArray> mList;
    private TotalVolumeInterface mTotalVolumeInterface;
    private AnimalVolumeChangeListener mAnimalVolumeChangeListener;
    private double volume = 0;

    public Animal_Volume_Adapter(ArrayList<AnimalsArray> list,
                                 TotalVolumeInterface totalVolumeInterface,
                                 AnimalVolumeChangeListener animalVolumeChangeListener) {
        this.mList = list;
        this.mTotalVolumeInterface = totalVolumeInterface;
        this.mAnimalVolumeChangeListener = animalVolumeChangeListener;
    }
```

-> Set the interfaces you passed as parameters to their corresponding viewholders when they are being created

```
@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case AnimalsArray.TOP:
                View top = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.animal_top_layout, parent, false);
                return new Top(top);
            case AnimalsArray.MIDDLE:
                View data = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.animal_middle_layout, parent, false);
                Middle middleHolder = new Middle(data);
                middleHolder.setAnimalVolumeChangeListener(mAnimalVolumeChangeListener);
                return middleHolder;
            case AnimalsArray.BOTTOM:
                View footer = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.animal_bottom_layout, parent, false);
                Bottom bottomHolder = new Bottom(footer);
                bottomHolder.setTotalVolumeInterface(mTotalVolumeInterface);
                return bottomHolder;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Modified ViewHolder classes

```
static class Middle extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Context context;
    EditText weight;
    EditText quantity;
    TextView volume;
    AnimalVolumeChangeListener animalVolumeChangeListener;

    Middle(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        volume = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.volume);
        weight = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        quantity= (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    }

    public void setAnimalVolumeChangeListener(AnimalVolumeChangeListener animalVolumeChangeListener) {
        this.animalVolumeChangeListener = animalVolumeChangeListener;
    }

}

static class Bottom extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView volume;
    TotalVolumeInterface totalVolumeInterface;

    Bottom(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        volume = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.volumeText);


    }

    public void setTotalVolumeInterface(TotalVolumeInterface totalVolumeInterface) {
        this.totalVolumeInterface = totalVolumeInterface;
    }

}
```

-> Call methods from your interface in onBindViewHolder whenever they are needed.

In your case you need to have a way of identifying the `Middle` ViewHolders whose total volume contributes to the value of a `Bottom` ViewHolder(thus below I used `groupId` to represent this parameter).

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final AnimalsArray object = mList.get(position);

        /* middle holders contributing to the total volume of the same have the
         *same groupId together with their corressponding bottom holder.
         *TODO: Assigned this value in accordance to however you are assigning Middle ViewHolders to Bottom ViewHolders*/
        int groupId = 0;

        if (object != null) {
            switch (object.getCategory()) {

                case AnimalsArray.TOP:
                    break;


                case AnimalsArray.MIDDLE:

                    Middle middleHolder = (Middle) holder;


                    middleHolder.weight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                                      int arg3) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                            //While this edittext is being changed, I would like the 3rd viewtype which contains the volume to be calculated on the fly as the user enters numbers in this field.


                            String volumeBeforeChange = middleHolder.volume.getText().toString();
                            double previousVolume = Double.parseDouble(volumeBeforeChange);

                            if (arg0.toString().isEmpty() || arg0.toString().length() <= 0 || arg0.toString().equals("") || arg0.toString() == null || arg0.toString().equals("0") || arg0.toString().startsWith(".")) {
                                middleHolder.weight.setText("0");
                                middleHolder.animalVolumeChangeListener.onAnimalVolumeChanged(middleHolder.groupId,previousVolume,0);
                            } else {
                                volume = calculateWarmUpVolume(context, arg0.toString(), ((Middle) holder).quantity.getText().toString());
                                middleHolder.animalVolumeChangeListener.onAnimalVolumeChanged(middleHolder.groupId,previousVolume,volume);

                            }
                        }
                    });


                    middleHolder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                                      int arg3) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                            //While this edittext is being changed, I would like the 3rd viewtype which contains the volume to be calculated on the fly as the user enters numbers in this field.

                            String volumeBeforeChange = middleHolder.volume.getText().toString();
                            double previousVolume = Double.parseDouble(volumeBeforeChange);

                            if (arg0.toString().isEmpty() || arg0.toString().length() <= 0 || arg0.toString().equals("") || arg0.toString() == null || arg0.toString().equals("0") || arg0.toString().startsWith(".")) {
                                ((Middle) holder).quantity.setText("0");
                                middleHolder.animalVolumeChangeListener.onAnimalVolumeChanged(middleHolder.groupId,previousVolume,0);
                            } else {
                                volume = calculateWarmUpVolume(context, ((Middle) holder).weight.getText().toString(), arg0.toString());
                                middleHolder.animalVolumeChangeListener.onAnimalVolumeChanged(middleHolder.groupId,previousVolume,volume);

                            }
                        }
                    });

                    break;


                case AnimalsArray.BOTTOM:

                    Bottom bottomHolder = ((Bottom) holder);


                    Pair<LifecycleOwner, LiveData<Double>> totalVolumePair = bottomHolder.totalVolumeInterface.getTotalVolume(groupId);
                    totalVolumePair.second.observe(totalVolumePair.first,
                            new Observer<Double>(){
                                @Override
                                public void onChanged(Double aDouble) {
                                    //Check if double is a whole number. If it is, remove decimal by converting to integer
                                    String volumedWeight;
                                    if ((aDouble % 1) == 0) {
                                        int roundedVolume = aDouble.intValue();
                                        volumedWeight = Integer.toString(roundedVolume);
                                    } else {
                                        volumedWeight = Double.toString(volume);
                                    }

                                    bottomHolder.volume.setText(String.valueOf(volumedWeight));
                                }
                            }
                    );


                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        /* middle holders contributing to the total volume of the same have the
         *same groupId together with their corressponding bottom holder.
         */
        int groupId = 0;
        if(holder instanceof Bottom){
            ((Bottom) holder).totalVolumeInterface.removeObservers(groupId);
        }
    }
```

-> And finally write logic for overridden methods of your interfaces.

```
public class SetupRecyclerClass extends AppCompatActivity implements TotalVolumeInterface, AnimalVolumeChangeListener{

    HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<Double>> mTotalVolumesMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<AnimalsArray> animalsArrayArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Animal_Volume_Adapter adapter = new Animal_Volume_Adapter(animalsArrayArrayList,this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Pair<LifecycleOwner, LiveData<Double>> getTotalVolume(int groupId) {

        if(mTotalVolumesMap.get(groupId) == null){
            mTotalVolumesMap.put(groupId,new MutableLiveData<>(0.0));
        }

        return new Pair<>(this,mTotalVolumesMap.get(groupId));
    }

    @Override
    public void removeObservers(int groupId) {

        mTotalVolumesMap.get(groupId).removeObservers(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimalVolumeChanged(int groupId, double previousVolume, double currentVolume) {
        if(mTotalVolumesMap.get(groupId) == null){
            mTotalVolumesMap.put(groupId,new MutableLiveData<>(0.0));
        }

        double newTotalVolume = (mTotalVolumesMap.get(groupId).getValue()-previousVolume)+currentVolume;
        mTotalVolumesMap.get(groupId).setValue(newTotalVolume);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked! THANK YOU! Made very very slight changes to the code to get it to work but your answer definitely made this happen. I revised the OP that shows the revised code. Thank you again Networks!